# Conflicts in using both jQuery and prototype

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to use both jQuery and prototype scripts without having any collisions or overwritten variables? I don't know if since I last used prototype a few months back this has been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to use both jQuery and prototype scripts without having any collisions or overwritten variables?

Of course. Just use [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noconflict).

Answer (score 2):

`$` is used by both and I believe this is the source of conflict.

Since your previous code is in prototype so it is better to keep it as it is, you just make sure no jQuery code face conflict with prototype by $.

For this, wrap your code in a function and pass jQuery object to that function. Do as I describe below:

**If your code is:**

```
/* begin  */

// your variables
// your functions which $ goes here
// other stuff

/* end */
```

**Then, transform this as follows:**

```
(function($) {

  /* begin  */

  // your variables
  // your functions which uses $ is safe now; inside this code block.
  // other stuff

  /* end */

})(jQuery); // passing jQuery removes conflict, ta-da :-)
```

Comment: It's still necessary to call `jQuery.noConflict()` after importing the library, or else the global "$" may be overwritten (depends on which library is imported first).

Comment: @Pointy: Im not sure...After passing JQuery i think $ is just another local variable to that scope defined by the function and global $ has no scope in that function.......So $ from JQuery is used/updated in that function only (think so)

Comment: The global "$" gets overwritten when you import the jQuery library in its own `<script>` tag, which you'd still need to do here.

Comment: @Pointy I see, didn't know this info about bydefault overwriting...But i think If someone want to use $ inside his code where $ comes from JQuery then he/she do not want the global $ (whatever it is)........On the other hand if he/she think of using global $ (defined by other) to use inside JQuery then it is handy to use JQuery notation instead of $......pathetic although, jquery should have call noconflict by default

Comment: the trick is that jQuery provides a method to "restore" the previous value of "$" - you import the library in a `<script>` tag, and then you follow that immediately with a little in-line script that just does `jQuery.noConflict();`, and it fixes things back up.