# Make Prototype and tokeninput.js files work together

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, conflict, jquery-tokeninput

Im using following JS file on my page

https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/blob/master/src/jquery.tokeninput.js

but Im also having Prototype.js file attached on same page and first script is not working because of Prototype. Can anyone tell me what changes I need to make using

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

so tokeninput.js can work. Hope someone understand what Im trying to ask. Regards.

Comment: Have you tried using `noConflict()` yet? There are plenty of prior examples. That should be all that is required.

Comment: I did few changes but none of them actually worked :(

Comment: is there anyone else maybe able to give more suggestion on how to make this work, I did tried to apply noConflict() on many ways but none did work, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi I was in the same situation but i have found a solution i would like to share with you
This is it:
1) Insert your prototype and other library first 
2) Insert your jquery library and token input library ex:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-tokeninput/jquery.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-tokeninput/src/jquery.tokeninput.js"></script>
```

3)Insert the

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.noConflict();
</script>
```

and

4) Insert the following code and place every other jquery code between the ////

```
<script type="text/javascript">


jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////





});


</script>
```

I did it and it worked perfectly. I have prototype.js, jquery.js, protoplasm, prototypericheditor, prototip.js all running on the same page and doing their own thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going on right track use anything like

```
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

and then

```
    j(function() {
    ...
    your token-input code goes here. 
    ...
    });
```

Post here if that doesn't work.

Comment: not working, I did wrapped the entire code within tokeninput.js using j(function() { }); but nothing, when ever I apply prototype.js file on that page tokeninput.js doesnot work

Comment: Use Break Down Approach see if token-input works after removing prototype from code. Just make sure your results are in suggested id,name JSON format then check.
BTW which server side programming language are you using?

Comment: thanks what I did first and I discovered its not working because of prototype. Every time I remove prototype.js file from the page jquery.tokeninput.js script from that file works just fine. I also found similar suggestions like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759284/conflicts-in-using-both-jquery-and-prototype but its not working in my case. I am using PHP

Comment: If you can paste your jquery code here. May be able to help.
I have faced similar problems in RoR but was able to solve.

Comment: Im using the same jquery you can find here https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/blob/master/src/jquery.tokeninput.js